# Validar registros duplicados codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validación

Hola estoy usando validacion sin libreria  form_validation, con ajax envio los datos del modal y los guarda y me muestra el mensaje de guardado  pero necesito validar si son duplicados con dos campos   de la tabla categorias. he intentado agregando el metodo validar en el modelo y luego en el controlador me gustaria devolver un mensaje a la vista. Si bien no me guarda los duplicados no puedo hacer que muestre el mensaje de registro duplicado. Adjunto el script, el  controlador y el modelo .Por favor necesito ayuda ... Desde ya muchas gracias...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

function agregar(){


var catename= document.getElementById('categorie-name').value;
var catedesc = document.getElementById('categorie-desc').value;
var idarea= document.getElementById('idarea').value;
if(catename.trim().length == 0 || catename == 0 || catename < 0){


    alertify.alert( "Atención","Por favor ingrese un nombre válido");

   }else{
     $.ajax({

      url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'ccategoria/agregarcat/' ?>",
      method: 'POST',
      data:{
        'catename':catename,
        'catedesc':catedesc,
        'idarea':idarea
      },
      success:function(data){

        if(data == 1){
         alertify.alert( "Atención","Registro duplicado");
         return false;

       }else{

        alertify.alert( "Atención","Los datos fueron agregados con exito");
        $('#categorie-name').val("");
        $('#categorie-desc').val("");
      }
    }



   });

}
}



</script>
```

// controlador ccategoria.php

```
<?php

/**
*
*/
class Ccategoria extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('mcategoria');
  $this->load->view('layout/header');
  $this->load->view('layout/menu');
}

public function index() {
  $this->load->view('layout/footer');
  $data['procat'] = $this->mcategoria->getcate();
  $this->load->view('producto/vcategoria', $data);
}

public function agregarcat() {

  $nombre = $this->input->post('catename');
  $idarea = $this->input->post('idarea');
  $descrip = $this->input->post('catedesc');
  $r = $this->mcategoria->validar($nombre, $idarea);

  if ($r == 1) {
    echo '1';
  } 
  else {
    $info = array(
      'id_categoria' => '',
      'name' => $nombre,
      'id_area' => $idarea,
      'desc_cat' => $descrip,
     );
     $this->mcategoria->insert($info);
   }

  }
}

?>
```

// en el modelo existen 2 metodos uno validar y el otro insert

```
 public function validar($nombre, $idarea) {
    $select = "id_area, name";
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->from('categorias');
    $this->db->where('categorias.id_area', $idarea);
    $this->db->where('categorias.name', $nombre);
    $consulta = $this->db->get();
    if ($consulta->num_rows() > 0) {

        return 1;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function insert($data) {

    $this->db->insert('categorias', $data);
}
```

Comment: ¿La alerta de cuando el registro ha sido exitoso si te lo muestra?

Comment: Gracias por contestar, perdón la alerta de registro exitoso si la muestra , pero no muestra la alerta de Registro duplicado

Comment: ¿Si imprimes por consola la respuesta de data que sale?

Comment: Hola, perdón no he podido resolver el problema de validación, no entiendo que pasa porque si guarda el registro si no existe y muestra el mensaje de "agregado con exito", y no me guarda el registro  si esta duplicado en la BD  pero no muestra el mensaje de error, me devuelve el mensaje de "agregado con exito" otra vez , creo que fallo en  el modelo, el método "validar" no retorna algo que comprenda el controlador. Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el contructor del controlador. Al cargar ahí las vistas, estás ocasionando que la llamada **AJAX** te devuelva, además del `echo` también las vistas correspondientes a:

```
$this->load->view('layout/header');
$this->load->view('layout/menu');
```

Con quitarlas de ahí conseguirías devolver tan solo lo que corresponde.